# Грамотно ли составлено предложение? (2)

Tags: грамотная-речь, деепричастный-оборот

Приводя пример из жизни, хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери "451 градус по Фаренгейту".

Comment: Правильно: «451 градус по **Ф**аренгейту», «Тридцать семь градусов по **Ц**ельсию» (Л. Альдани), «Тридцать пять градусов по **Ц**ельсию» (А. Прокопович), «Ниже 120 градусов по **К**ельвину» (Ф. Патрунов).

Comment: Звучит не очень. Попахивает тавтологией "приводя пример из жизни, хочу привести пример из романа...". Да и "из жизни" плохо сочетается с "из романа", типа определитесь уже.

Comment: Для примера из жизни можно обратиться к роману Брэдбери, в котором описывается реальная жизненная ситуация итд...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы деепричастный оборот был правильно употреблён, он должен относится к подлежащему. Ваше предложение является односоставным определённо-личным. В определённо-личных предложениях пропущено подлежащее, как в неполных, но такие предложения не считаются неполными просто потому, что так была выстроена терминология. Но относится к ним следует как к неполным, то есть считать подлежащее просто пропущенным. То есть в этом предложении пропущено ‟я” (слушающий воспринимает это предложение, как если бы это ‟я” было) — «Приводя пример из жизни, я хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери "451 градус по Фаренгейту”» — и деепричастный оборот относится к этому ‟я”, так что предложение грамматически верное. Никто не может сказать, что оно неграмотное, потому что оно идеально звучит для носителя и мы отчётливо понимаем, что деепричастие относится к пропущенному подлежащему ‟я”.

Comment: А что здесь с временным соотношением? Человек только собирается привести пример. Действия не одновременные. Ну и смысл: то, что в романе, не пример из жизни.

Comment: Приводя пример = когда я нахожусь в процессе приведения примера.

Comment: Ну он ещё не находится в процессе, он только хочет привести, это перед. Это как: *Готовя еду, собираюсь открыть кулинарную книгу, чтобы посмотреть рецепт.* Вроде бы там задумывается такое: *Для того, чтобы привести пример...*

Answer (score 1):

*"Приводя пример из жизни, хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери "451 градус по фаренгейту,"* - относительно грамотно, слова вроде те, а логической связи между частями нет.

*Смотря в окно, хочу обратится к роману.*

*Сидя на стуле, хочу вспомнить о лете.*

То есть логической согласованности между двумя частями предложения нет.

**Зачем ты хочешь обратится к роману Брэдбери?**
Для того, чтобы рассмотреть случай из жизни.

*Рассматривая случай из жизни, хочу обратится к Брэдбери...*(его личность поможет мне,  посмотреть на событие из жизни под определенным углом, хочу посмотреть на случай из жизни его глазами)

Либо

*Приводя **пример из литературы**, хочу обратиться **к роману**...(как к литературному аргументу)*

Но может автор просто описывает очередность действий:

"Сидя на диване, смотрю в окно, обращаюсь к роману, хочу поесть..." Так что не ясно, где именно употреблена данная фраза. Если в "сочинении" (которое эссе по ЕГЭ) - то скорее всего неграмотно, если в дневнике - то почему нет.

Ошибка же в том, что "рассказ из жизни" - это *документалистика*, а роман(по крайней мере этот, фантастический) - это *художественная литература*. Жанры разные и несочетаемые, так что назвать одно другим - это **ошибка шаблона**.

Но, конечно, находчивый писака, всегда может выкрутиться из сложной ситуации:

*Жизнь человека подобна книге, автором и героем которой является он сам. Поэтому, приводя пример из жизни, я обращусь к роману Брэдбери...* - но это уже не шаблон, а игра смыслов, что ли.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146548/discussion-on-answer-by------2); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Опущенное подлежащее не является поводом считать фразу неграмотно составленной. Но логичное обращение к литературным произведениям, в общем случае нормальное, здесь выглядит сомнительным: с примерами жизненными, только что заявленными, происходит нечто, что может быть похоже и на обидную паузу, и на возможную подмену фактов вымыслом. Необходим намёк на то, что это не так:

*Приводя пример из жизни, вначале хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери «451 градус по Фаренгейту».*

Answer (score 1):

То, что некоторым не нравится такая связка, вовсе не означает, что ее нельзя использовать. **Оборот составлен грамматически верно** (подлежащее восстанавливается по контексту). Через эту связку **ученик прописывает свою логику**, и в этом нет ошибки: *я привожу пример из жизни, для этого я обращаюсь к роману...*

---

**Что касается самого шаблона.**
В ОГЭ ученик должен показать, что научился связывать абзацы друг с другом. Тот, кто знаком с форматом сдачи ОГЭ по РЯ, знает, что ученик должен привести пример из жизненного опыта. Если же он просто напишет, что взял пример из жизненного опыта, то эксперты-проверяющие могут счесть это нарушением структуры сочинения, если до этого ученик никак логику движения мыслей не объяснил.

---

Такая связка помогает ученику, который сам не может подобрать нужных слов, чтобы корректно построить предложение, убить сразу двух зайцев: внести в текст связочный компонент и положить начало новому абзацу - примеру-аргументу из жизненного опыта.

Answer (score 0):

***Приводя пример из жизни, хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери "451 градус по Фаренгейту.***

1. **Способы связи предложений в тексте** — это  тема, которая изучается в школе, и выпускники должны на практике показать, как они усвоили ее, например: [Способы связи предложений](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/sposoby-svyazi-predlozhenij-v-tekste)
2. В тексте-рассуждении важна **логика**, поэтому связному изложению мыслей  уделяется много внимания. Разработаны даже особые приемы — так называемые  **связки-клише.** Но нужно ли их применять? Из заданного предложения хочется эту связку **решительно удалить**, заменив ее любой другой фразой, например: «В литературе можно найти немало примеров…»
3. Чем эта фраза с деепричастным оборотом **еще нехороша** (кроме того, что это шаблон)?  **Грамматическая стилистика** здесь сомнительная. Отсутствие  подлежащего не напрягает — для определенно-личных предложений это норма.  Речь идет о значении деепричастного оборота.

Обороты обычно  являются **ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВАМИ** различного вида (аналогами соответствующих придаточных предложений).  И вот в данном случае оборот приобретает, как мне кажется, значение обстоятельства **ЦЕЛИ**  (или причины): я должен (по плану ответа) привести пример из жизни, так вот вам, пожалуйста. Слишком откровенно обозначена цель… **Или какое здесь обстоятельство?**

Без решения этого вопроса нежелательно использовать такую конструкцию. Грамматически верная, она тем не менее показывает недостаточно высокий (**подчеркнуто школьный**)  уровень знаний и умений при составлении текстов.

Можно посмотреть учебный материал
[Предложения с деепричастными оборотами](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/786-36_predlozheniya_s_deeprichastnymi_oborotami.html)

Таким образом, **семантическая правильность** предложений с деепричастными оборотами не менее важна, чем грамматическая, и обращаться с ними надо осмотрительно. Вот и модальный глагол "*хочу*" тоже, вероятно, не так уж нейтрален. Чем-то он мне тоже не нравится:)

**P.S.** Уважаемые участники, если вам не нравятся статьи, то найдите другой материал по теме (вашего/высокого уровня, а не школьного). Я же написала: "например, можно посмотреть". Здесь важно **напомнить,** что есть теория по указанным вопросам. А **школьникам** даже это знать очень неплохо.

"*В то время, когда привожу пример из жизни, я хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери*..."  Никак **не могу понять** эту фразу...

Comment: Причинное деепричастие такое: ‟Устав на работе, он быстро заснул”. Оборот в вопросе временной, он заменяется на: ‟Во то время, когда привожу пример из жизни, я хочу обратиться к роману Брэдбери "451 градус по Фаренгейту". А где в этой статье про предложения с деепричастными оборотами сказано про ‟‟‟семантическую правильность”””?

Comment: И кстати, статья ужасная, там 3 пункта правильных, а остальное либо вода (бесполезная для любого человека на планете информация), либо чушь. Деревенские жители профессиональней строят деревенские толчки, чем лингвисты пишут свои учебные пособия.

Comment: Да, наверное, надо их по лицу ударить...

Comment: Вам надо чётче формулировать свои мысли. Из всего ответа понял одно — что предложение вам не нравится. Вы не можете чётко сказать, что здесь не так. Мне тоже не нравится. Обратите внимание на соотношение действий. Здесь нет одновременности.

Comment: Это ваши проблемы, что не поняли. Я не репетитор. Напоминаю, что в комментариях можно не критиковать,  а уточнить ответ или предложить его улучшение.  Улучшить вааше понимание я не могу, да и нет желания. Критику в комментариях не читаю, так что беседуйте между собой. Здесь не чат, а сайт вопросов и ответов со своими правилами. Их нужно соблюдать. Если мне надоедят нападки с разных сторон, то отвечать просто не буду. У любой проблемы есть решение.

Comment: Чего критика? Просто пожелание. И помощь (про соотношение). Так у вас же форум...

Comment: Мне не нужна помощь, спасибо. Если хотите заняться чем-нибудь полезным, то отвечайте на вопросы тем людям, которым нужны наши знания.

Comment: Я бесплатно не работаю.

Comment: А как вы понимаете вашу задачу на форуме?

Comment: У меня нет задачи. Иногда хочется опровергнуть ерунду, когда вижу её. А здесь хотелось от вас услышать по поводу временной соотнесённости...

Comment: Понятно...  Здесь у вас задача не созидательная, а разрушительная. Извините,  но у меня сейчас уже нет времени для ответа на ваш вопрос. Пожалуйста, проконсультируйтесь с другими участниками. И пожалуй все, не будем нарушать правила.

Comment: Разрушать неправду — это благое дело.

Comment: Вы можете позже сказать, что думаете, никто вас не торопит. Если вы можете что-то сказать...

Comment: Из правил сайта: Когда стоит оставлять комментарий? Комментарий нужно оставить, если вы хотите: представить конструктивную **критику**, которая поможет автору улучшить сообщение. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment Так что всё. Критика здесь в рамках закона :)

Comment: Возможно, что и так. Но здесь есть проблема: это вы считаете свою критику конструктивной и улучшающей (ваше мнение), а другие так не думают, в том числе автор ответа и модератор сайта. Про действия модератора можно  догадаться, а я продолжаю в этом случае разговор и уточняю  то, что мне нужно. Если молчу, значит, у меня другое мнение.  Спасибо за ваше внимание, до свидания. :)

Comment: С модератором говорил, он просто против длинных дискуссий. Он сказал, что раньше тоже делал такое (оставлял критику), и сейчас он это советует. Конструктивная критика — это когда чётко указывается, в чём проблема, у меня всегда так. А неконструктивная — это когда говорят общие негативные вещи (например, "вообще не понравилось", "ничего не поняла" — ваша коронная фраза, "это полный бред"). Не знаю, с чего вы взяли про автора ответа, они не получают оповещения о комментариях под ответами.

Comment: Да я про себя говорю: я могу не считать вашу критику уточняющей, улучшающей и конструктивной, и тогда я не отвечаю на нее.  Мне не нравится возвращаться к старым темам, это тоже мое право – не отвечать на что-то давнее, когда на форуме много новых интересных вопросов. А модератор действует по своему усмотрению, и мне сейчас нравится модерация. Есть надежда, что на форуме будет больше культуры и порядка..

Comment: А ещё модератор сказал, что этот сайт позиционирует себя не как форум, а как энциклопедия в виде вопросов и ответов, поэтому они против длинных дискуссий. Да просто вы не хотите исправлять ответы и становиться лучше. Критика сама по себе конструктивная, если указывается, что именно не так. Ничего в модерации не изменилось.

Comment: Все уже пересказали?..

Comment: Вроде бы да... –